# Sage Pay / Opayo Credential on File ERROR 3370 : The RelatedVPSTxId cannot be repeated (PHP/cURL solution)

Tags: php, mysql, curl, opayo, sage-erp

## QUESTION

I get an **ERROR 3370** from Sage Pay when trying to repeat transactions of type **AUTHORISE** (but not **PAYMENT**). I am using **Server Integration** with PHP/cURL.

---

## ANSWER

This is most likely because you need to send CoF values ***during your initial AUTHENTICATE*** transaction. This establishes the initial record as a valid "Credentital on File" and allows you to carry out **REPEAT** transactions later.

In a nutshell, the initial **AUTHENTICATE** record must be created with:

```
COFUsage = FIRST
InitiatedType = CIT
MITType = UNSCHEDULED
```

**HERE IS THE FULL PHP/CURL CODE THAT IS NOW WORKING FOR ME:**

---

### STEP 1: AUTHENTICATE

Assuming you are using **Server Integration** and the customer is "in session" your initial cURL code will look something like this:

```
// Initialise cURL
$curl = curl_init();
```

```
// Set the Sage Pay server URL
$serverLive="https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/authorise.vsp";
```

```
// Connect to the Sage Pay server
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $serverLive);
```

```
// Set cURL to post variables
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

```
// Declare account variables for posting to the Sage Pay server
$VPSProtocol="4.0"; // Must be 4.0 for CoF usage 
$Vendor="......."; // Your Sage Pay Vendor Name
```

```
// Declare product variables for posting to the Sage Pay server
$Amount=0.01; // This transaction will be for 1 pence
$Currency="GBP";
$Description="......."; // Product description
```

```
// Declare URL of your callback page for posting to the Sage Pay server
$NotificationURL="https://www.......";
```

```
// Create a unique 16-character VendorTxCode for posting to the Sage Pay server
$UserID=9999; // Unique user ID
$salt="d5s63ffd6s7fgdhs55377yrwesr24553"; // Encryption key
$VendorTxCode=substr(strtoupper(md5(date("U").$UserID.$salt)), 0, 16);
```

```
// Declare other variables to pass to Sage Pay (ie. customer name, email, billing address etc)
// These will have been entered via a form on your website
$CustomerName=".......";
$CustomerEmail=".......";
$BillingFirstnames=".......";
$BillingSurname=".......";
$BillingAddress1=".......";
$BillingCity=".......";
$BillingPostCode=".......";
$BillingCountry="GB";
$BillingPhone=".......";
$DeliveryFirstnames=".......";
$DeliverySurname=".......";
$DeliveryAddress1=".......";
$DeliveryCity=".......";
$DeliveryPostCode=".......";
$DeliveryCountry="GB";
$DeliveryPhone=".......";
```

Now is probably a good time to INSERT these variables into your MySQL database. Create a table called "sagepay" with field/values as follows:

- userID = $UserID
- VendorTxCode = $VendorTxCode
- TxType = AUTHENTICATE
- Amount = $Amount
- Description = $Description

You should also have the following fields in your sagepay database table. These will start off empty and will be UPDATE(d) later:

- SecurityKey
- VPSTxId
- TxAuthNo
- RelatedVendorTxCode
- RelatedSecurityKey
- RelatedVPSTxId
- RelatedTxAuthNo
- SchemeTraceID
- ACSTransID
- DSTransID
- Status

Now post your variables to the Sage Pay server via cURL. Your cURL post should send a **$COFUsage** value of **FIRST** to correspond with this being an initial **AUTHENTICATE** transaction and **$InitiatedType** must be set to **CIT** to indicate the customer is "in session" (ie. they are going to enter their payment details on your website in a moment):

```
// Post the variables to the Sage Pay server
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('Profile' => 'LOW', 'VPSProtocol' => $VPSProtocol, 'Vendor' => $Vendor, 'TxType' => 'AUTHENTICATE', 'VendorTxCode' => $VendorTxCode, **'Apply3DSecure' => '1', 'COFUsage' => 'FIRST', 'InitiatedType' => 'CIT',** 'Amount' => $Amount, 'Currency' => $Currency, 'Description' => $Description, 'CustomerName' => $CustomerName, 'CustomerEMail' => $CustomerEmail, 'BillingFirstnames' => $BillingFirstnames, 'BillingSurname' => $BillingSurname, 'BillingAddress1' => $BillingAddress1, 'BillingCity' => $BillingCity, 'BillingPostCode' => $BillingPostCode, 'BillingCountry' => $BillingCountry, 'BillingPhone' => $BillingPhone, 'DeliveryFirstnames' => $DeliveryFirstnames, 'DeliverySurname' => $DeliverySurname, 'DeliveryAddress1' => $DeliveryAddress1, 'DeliveryCity' => $DeliveryCity, 'DeliveryPostCode' => $DeliveryPostCode, 'DeliveryCountry' => $DeliveryCountry, 'DeliveryPhone' => $DeliveryPhone, 'NotificationURL' => $NotificationURL', 'Status' => 'OK'
)));
```

```
// This is supposed to speed things up (not sure if it does!)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

```
// Request a response from cURL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

The above code will create an **AUTHENTICATE** record on the Sage Pay server and return a cURL string containing values that you will use to UPDATE your previously created database record. These variables will be reused when you create the **AUTHORISE** transaction (see Step 2):

```
// Get server response
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

```
// Close cURL
curl_close ($curl);
```

Convert the **$response string** into an array called $results[]:

```
// Convert $response string into an array called $results[]
$results = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $response) as $line) 
{
  list ($key, $value) = explode('=', $line, 2);
  $results[$key] = trim($value); // Trim to remove white space
}
```

The following variables are contained in the **$results[]** array. Make sure you UPDATE your initial **AUTHENTICATE** database record with these values. You will need to recall them when you come to **AUTHORISE** the transaction and take the first payment:

```
$SecurityKey=$results['SecurityKey']; // Save this to your database
$VPSTxId=$results['VPSTxId']; // Save this to your database
```

**$results[]** will also contain the following variable:

```
$NextURL=$results['NextURL'];
```

Once an **AUTHENTICATE** record is created on the Sage Pay server, you can display a card payment page to your customer using an iFrame with the source URL set to **$NextURL**

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="<?= $NextURL ?>" width='100%' height='520'></iframe>
```

At this point the customer will enter their card details and, if everything is in order, the transaction will be completed and the iFrame will update with your **$NotificationURL**

Sage Pay will pass the following variables to your **$NotificationURL** in the $_REQUEST[] array. It is a good idea to "trim" these values to ensure no white space creeps in:

```
$Status=trim($_REQUEST['Status']); // This should be "OK"
$TxAuthNo=trim($_REQUEST['TxAuthNo']);
$ACSTransID=trim($_REQUEST['ACSTransID']);
$DSTransID=trim($_REQUEST['DSTransID']);
```

UPDATE your "sagepay" database table with these values and then display your "Thank You" message.

---

### STEP 2: AUTHORISE

Now you have an **AUTHENTICATE** record on the Sage Pay server, and a corresponding record in your MySQL database table, you must **AUTHORISE** the transaction to take the initial payment. This involves creating a new **AUTHORISE** record on the Sage Pay server and in your MySQL database.

First, create a new 16-character **$VendorTxCode** for the **AUTHORISE** record.

Then, SELECT and transfer the values from the original **AUTHENTICATE** record into "related" variables for resubmission to Sage Pay:

```
// Declare "related" variables
$RelatedVendorTxCode = $VendorTxCode; // The original VendorTxCode you created
$RelatedVPSTxId = $VPSTxId; // The $VPSTxId returned in $results[] array  
$RelatedSecurityKey = $SecurityKey; // The $SecurityKey returned in $results[] array
```

Now is a good time to INSERT the **$VendorTxCode** and these "related" variables as a new record in your MySQL database. Set the **TxType** field for this new record to **AUTHORISE**.

Next, pass your variables to Sage Pay via cURL to create an **AUTHORISE** record on the Sage Pay server. Note, the **$InitiatedType** is now **MIT** to indicate the customer is no longer "in session", but the **$COFUsage** value still needs to be **FIRST**:

```
// Create an AUTHORISE record
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('VPSProtocol' => $VPSProtocol, 'VendorTxCode' => $VendorTxCode, 'Vendor' => $Vendor, 'TxType' => 'AUTHORISE', **'Apply3DSecure' => '1', 'COFUsage' => 'FIRST', 'InitiatedType' => 'MIT', 'MITType' => 'UNSCHEDULED',** 'Amount' => $Amount, 'Description' => $Description, 'RelatedVPSTxId' => $RelatedVPSTxId, 'RelatedVendorTxCode' => $RelatedVendorTxCode, 'RelatedSecurityKey' => $RelatedSecurityKey, 'RelatedTxAuthNo' => $RelatedTxAuthNo)));
```

Sage Pay will respond again with a string (**$response**). Convert **$response** into a **$results[]** array as before. These are some of the variables you will end up with:

```
$TxAuthNo
$VPSTxId
$SecurityKey
$SchemeTraceID
$ACSTransID
$DSTransID
$Status
```

UPDATE the **AUTHORISE** record in your MySQL database table with these variables. You will need these variables for when you come to **REPEAT** the transaction.

**$TxAuthNo** is an authorisation code which is only returned if the **AUTHORISE** record is successfully created on the Sage Pay server (ie. if **$Status** is "OK").

**$SchemeTraceID** is your CoF "token" for repeating successful **AUTHORISE** transactions.

---

### STEP 3: REPEAT

You can **REPEAT** against **AUTHORISE** transactions using the following cURL code. Note, the **$COFUsage** value now changes from **FIRST** to **SUBSEQUENT** and you must send the **$SchemeTraceID** (token) to verify the transaction as a valid "Credential on File". The "related" variables are those of the original **AUTHORISE** record (ie. $VendorTxCode, $TxAuthNo, $VPSTxId, and $SecurityKey):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('VPSProtocol' => $VPSProtocol, 'Vendor' => $Vendor, 'TxType' => 'REPEAT', 'VendorTxCode' => $VendorTxCode, **'Apply3DSecure' => '1', 'COFUsage' => 'SUBSEQUENT', 'InitiatedType' => 'MIT', 'MITType' => 'UNSCHEDULED', 'SchemeTraceID'=> $SchemeTraceID,** 'Amount' => $Amount, 'Currency' => $Currency, 'Description' => $Description, 'RelatedVPSTxId' => $RelatedVPSTxId, 'RelatedVendorTxCode' => $RelatedVendorTxCode, 'RelatedSecurityKey' => $RelatedSecurityKey, 'RelatedTxAuthNo' => $RelatedTxAuthNo )));
```

Comment: Hi. Really sorry as I'm not answering your question, but how did you do your AUTHORISE step? I can do the AUTHENTICATE no problem (using a Transaction Registration call to https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp. I simply can't find the AUTHORISE API reference on SagePay's documentation. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jon. I have updated this post with all the PHP/cURL code I am using to AUTHENTICATE, AUTHORISE, and REPEAT with CoF tokens. See STEP 2: AUTHORISE (above). Hope this helps :) Regards, Daniel

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find the AUTHORISE API here https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-shared-api and have now built everything in C#.NET. I will try to post the solution online somewhere, as I couldn't find this anywhere and had to build it from scratch - I imagine, like you did.

Comment: @JonWeir did you manage to post this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. But I have used this library and reason behind this issue is in the first transaction request they(Sagepay server) are getting blank  COFUsage, InitiatedType, MITType params
https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay

I installed 4.0 version of omnipay-sagepay library rather then 3.0

```
{
"require": {
    "omnipay/sagepay": "~4.0"
}
}
```

and in the first transaction, I have passed these extra parameters.

```
 $gateway->setCOFUsage("FIRST");
 $gateway->setInitiatedType("CIT");
 $gateway->setMITType("UNSCHEDULED");
```

And for repeat transactions, I have passed these params

```
$gateway->setCOFUsage('SUBSEQUENT');
$gateway->setInitiatedType('MIT');
$gateway->setMITType('UNSCHEDULED');
$gateway->setSchemeTraceID($TransactionReference['scheme_trace_Id']);
```

and it's working fine for me. [Response from sagepay team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071pP.jpg)